# How to compare two WSDL files located in separate Web servers

Tags: wsdl, asmx, legacy

I'm using some legacy .asmx files. I need to compare if the WSDL from a Web Service located in Server A is exactly the same as WSDL in Server B.

The problem here is that when I get the **?wsdl** as XML and perform the comparison (using WinMerge or C# code), then both files are going to be different.

For instance, if you look at this WSDL file : http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?wsdl , you will find some information in the WSDL that belongs to this server exclusively :

```
<wsdl:service name="GlobalWeather">
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap">
<soap:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherSoap12" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherSoap12">
<soap12:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpGet" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpGet">
<http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
<wsdl:port name="GlobalWeatherHttpPost" binding="tns:GlobalWeatherHttpPost">
<http:address location="http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So the location is going to be different between servers.

Do you know any approach to achieve this task? And yes, ideally I want to do via C# code, by getting the WSDL from both servers and comparing them.

Comment: Search and replace should work.

Comment: like replacing the location to an arbitrary text like "service endpoint" in both of them?